# How to relate X-macro to array of function pointer

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, function-pointers, x-macros

I applied X-macro mechanism to get enumeration-to-string relation.

```
#define CMD_TABLE \
                     X(cmd_A)\
                     X(cmd_B)\
////////////////////////////////////
typedef enum
{
    EMPTY, 
#define X(x) x,
    CMD_TABLE
#undef X
}cmd_t;
////////////////////////////////////
const static struct
{
    char* name;
    cmd_t index;
} conversionMap[] = {
#define X(x) {#x, x},
        CMD_TABLE
#undef X
};
```

Then, this function converts string to enum.

```
cmd_t str2enum(const char* str);
```

Finally, corresponding function is called by treating enum as the index of array.

```
(*func[index])();
```

This method has a big problem that it force programmer to remember enum-to-function mapping relationship.

In other words, in initialization stage, the order of following functions

```
void (*func[])(void) = 
{
    &cmd_A_function,
    &cmd_B_function,
};
```

needs to be as same as that of `CMD_TABLE`.

Further, once `CMD_TABLE` grows, code is getting worse to maintain because

1. if a command is not going to support, people might delete wrong line in array of function pointer.
2. if I want to know what does `cmd_Z` do, I have to count up from 1 to 26.
3. list of `CMD_TABLE` and `void (*func[])(void)` will be far away from each other such that programmer needs to write code in *two places* in order to add one feature.

Comment: Why don't you use a third variant of the X macro? Or better, use the undef-free version of X-macros.

Comment: You could use your `CMD_TABLE` again, with an X macro that turns `X(cmd_A)` into `&cmd_A_function,`. True? But you do know how to that, don't you?

Comment: The `EMPTY` at start of the enum screws up the consistency between the enums and the array indices. Not a good idea.

Comment: Get rid of the first `EMPTY` enum, it will only bring problems with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have already used X-macro twice.
You can use it a third time.
Here is a proposal how to do that, using the ugly undef-using pattern you applied the first two times:

```
void (*func[])(void) = 
{
#define X(x) &x##_function,
    CMD_TABLE
#undef X
};
```

Comment: This kind of macros are tricky. If this fails for you please provide the output of a `-E` compiler run (i.e. the preprocessed code) and compare it to how it should be instead. I will then do my best to fix it.

Comment: Ugly or not, I believe this is the most common way to write X macros.

Comment: @Lundin Yes. Pity.

Comment: I came up with a alternative: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419695/what-design-component-principle-did-i-apply-how-can-i-further-improve-it